# Flutter BottomNavBar not showing BoxShadow

Tags: flutter, dart

I made a custom BottomNav Bar and wrapped it inside of a container so that I could give it some box shadow. But the box shadow does not apply. Here is the code

```dart
class CBottomNavBar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CBottomNavBarState createState() => _CBottomNavBarState();
}

class _CBottomNavBarState extends State<CBottomNavBar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<SManageIndex>(
      builder: (context, manageIndex, child) => Container(
        height: 80,
        clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: primaryColorDark,
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(color: primaryColorDark, blurRadius: 4, spreadRadius: 2)
            ],
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topRight: Radius.circular(20), topLeft: Radius.circular(20))),
        child: BottomNavigationBar(
          backgroundColor: primaryColorDark,
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(
                  FontAwesomeIcons.hospital,
                ),
                title: Text('Appointments')),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(
                FontAwesomeIcons.pills,
              ),
              title: Text('Medicines'),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(
                FontAwesomeIcons.bookMedical,
              ),
              title: Text('Documents'),
            ),
          ],
          currentIndex: manageIndex.index,
          onTap: (value) => manageIndex.changePage(value),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

The thing is I want both the border radius and box shadow, so I am using a container. Any other straightforward ways of doing the same are also welcome.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Offset does not work here

Answer (score 0):

You need the `Offset` property of the `BoxShadow`,

> The `offset` property is used to control the position of the shadow. It is `zero` by default so you'll need to add the `Offset`:

I added a demo using your widget tree as an example:

```
class CBottomNavBar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CBottomNavBarState createState() => _CBottomNavBarState();
}

class _CBottomNavBarState extends State<CBottomNavBar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<SManageIndex>(
      builder: (context, manageIndex, child) => Container(
        height: 80,
        clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: primaryColorDark,
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                 color: primaryColorDark, blurRadius: 4, spreadRadius: 2,
                 // add the offset property
                 offset: Offset(0, 5), // new line [move to the right[horizontally] by 0 ,move to the top[vertically] by 5]
            ),
            ],
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topRight: Radius.circular(20), topLeft: Radius.circular(20))),
        child: BottomNavigationBar(
          backgroundColor: primaryColorDark,
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(
                  FontAwesomeIcons.hospital,
                ),
                title: Text('Appointments')),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(
                FontAwesomeIcons.pills,
              ),
              title: Text('Medicines'),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(
                FontAwesomeIcons.bookMedical,
              ),
              title: Text('Documents'),
            ),
          ],
          currentIndex: manageIndex.index,
          onTap: (value) => manageIndex.changePage(value),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is `Offset`. Use [Offset class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Offset-class.html) in your `decoration` for `boxShadow` element, and you will be good do go

```
//dx is horiztonal and dy is vertical
// play with it
boxShadow: [BoxShadow(offset: Offset(dx, dy));
```